# c# generic interfaces and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

the chosen title for my question isn't quite precise, but I don't know the term I'm looking for or if it is even possible.

What I have in mind is a chain of consumer <- procucer <-product.
A consumer can "consume" producers and producers "produce" products of a certain type. Therefor I wrote:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    string ProductName { get;  }
}

public class Product : IProduct
{
    public string ProductName { get { return "name of product"; } }
}

public interface IProducer<T>
{
    T ProducerProperty { get; set; }

    void ProducerMethod();
}

public class Producer<T> : IProducer<T> where T : IProduct
{
    public Producer()
    {

    }
    public T ProducerProperty { get; set; }

    public void ProducerMethod()
    {

    }
}

public interface IConsumer<T>
{
    T ConsumerProperty { get; set; }
    void ConsumerMethod();
}

public class Consumer<T> : IConsumer<T>
{
    private U producer;           //U should be IProducer<IProduct>, doesen't work

    public Consumer(U producer)   //U should be IProducer<IProduct>, doesen't work 
    {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public T ConsumerProperty { get; set; }

    public void ConsumerMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

and the use case:

```
private IProducer<IProduct> producer;   //DeviceManager

private IConsumer<IProducer<IProduct>> consumer;  //DeviceViewManager            


public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    producer = new Producer<IProduct>();
    consumer = new Consumer<IProducer<IProduct>>();
}
```

The consumer class uses the generic "U", which is imaginary at this point. I want the consumer class to use the type U. In the context of the given example you could think of a user who consumes different types of noodles from different manufacrures of noodles.
 I want the generic classes be tied to the interfaces rather than to actual classes. But I culdn't manage to achieve this. I tried substituting the interfaces with base classes (e.g.: ProducerBase), but than the actual base classes were needed.

Comment: What would `U` be? It sounds like you want two type parameters.

Comment: In this case IProduct (I changed it in code)

Comment: I think you might want `IConsumer<T, U> where T : IProducer<U> where U : IProduct` and `IProducer<T> where T : IProduct`?

Comment: @juharr That sounds like the correct answer, why don't you post it?

Comment: If you eventually end up producing and consuming a sequence of `T` take a look at `IObserver<T>` in the .NET framework.

Comment: What does the `T` type in the consumer stands for?

Comment: Ok, I changed the interfaces, but on the implemantation of IConsumer<T, U> the compiler is unhapppy:
    
    public interface IConsumer<T, U> where T : IProducer<U> where U : IProduct
    {
        T ConsumerProperty { get; set; }
        void MethodB();
    }

<pre>Test<code>

Comment: These sound more like properties of an object than an inheritance chain. Not sure why you are using generics at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

If you define the `Consumer` class like this

```
public class Consumer<T, U> : IConsumer<T, U>
{
    ...
}
```

you get the errors

> CS0314 The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `IConsumer<T, U>`'. There is not boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to ''IProducer'.

and

> CS0314 The type 'U' cannot be used as type parameter 'U' in the generic type or method `IConsumer<T, U>`'. There is not boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'U' to ''IProducer'.

What this tells you is that you cannot derive from the `IConsumer<T, U>` interface, because it has *constraints* for its generic type parameters:

```
public interface IConsumer<T, U>
    where T : IProducer<U>   // T needs to "be" an IProducer<U>
    where U : IProduct       // U needs to "be" an IProduct
{
    ...
}
```

because **the interface expects** `T` and `U` to derive from `IProducer<U>` and `IProduct` respectively and **the compiler doesn't know** that the generic type parameters `T` and `U` of the `Consumer` class **can actually be converted** to an `IProducer<U>` and `IProduct` respectively.

---

## The Solution

Therefore, if you define the `Consumer` like this and add constraints for `T` and `U`

```
public class Consumer<T, U> : IConsumer<T, U>
    where T : IProducer<U>
    where U : IProduct
{
    ...
}
```

it will work because now you specified that `T` and `U` will always *be* an `IProducer<U>` and `IProduct` respectively.

---

I hope above explanation was understandable; either way, you should also read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for a good understanding of constraints on generic types.